# How to add Auth Header to HTML5 Video with Dynamic Source

Tags: javascript, video, authorization, html5-video

We have a Single Page Application, within which we have training video's for user to complete, before using the web app.
This videos are fetched from our backend API calls and are protected.
We were first using xhr calls to get the video blob object and append to videos, and this worked for us as we were able to append the Auth Headers to XHR calls, but the problem with this approach was it requires the entire video to be downloaded in order to play and thats a perf issue for us.

```
<video preload="metadata" width="645" height="375" controls id="trainingVideos" style="display:none;" controlsList="nodownload">
    <source id="source" src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```
var url = 'http:/localhost:8080/rest/v1.0/training/video/' + videoId;
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
if (jwtToken && jtiValidationToken) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("JTI-Validation-Token", jtiValidationToken);
}
```

Hence we changed the code, to use streaming way of getting the video, but in this case, we are unable to add the auth header to the media request of video and a small popup for username password is shown to user, even though he has logged in to the application using the credentials.

```
$("#source")[0].setAttribute("src", 'http:/localhost:8080/rest/v2.0/training/video/' + videoId);
```

How can I add Auth Header to above request?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you'd be looking to do is use the [Media Source Extensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) to fetch the video in chunks and append as a blob. You may look at using an external player library (like video.js or hls.js) to help.